# Installing Ruby on Rails on Synology NAS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, synology

I'm trying to install Rails on a DS213j Synology NAS using :

```
    $ gem install rails
```

but I keep getting this error :

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150707-4993-mpal0w.rb extconf.rb
    mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include /ruby.h

    extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/armle-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

I already have Ruby installed.
I tried to install `ruby-dev` and `ruby-devel` but I can't use `apt-get` nor `yum`... it keeps telling me it doesn't know these commands :(.

I cannot install `ipkg`because there is no bootstrap for this model, and curl doesn't work, it just tells me :

```
    curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 15755)
```

so yeah ... I'm a bit desperate now...
Thanks

Comment: I think "but I can't use apt-get nor yum" is your real problem here.

Comment: yeah it's realy frustrating... I heard Synology was good at web servers, so it seems strange they took those commands out

Comment: As what user were  you installing gems? As what user did you log in? admin? root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to install curl or ipkg (unsuccesfuly), I managed to set up a chroot debian system, where I could use apt-get and curl. 
I then installed rails using rvm, and it works fine now.